# Java Word Regular Expression

Tags: java, string, search, expression

I am quite bad at Java Regular expression so I hope you guys will help me.

```
String variable = "My life is better ";
String variable2 = "My life01 is better";
```

Now I have to write a code which would return true if the string has only "life"

So I should get TRUE only for variable not for variable2 because it has life but "01" too.

~thanks.

I have tried

```
if (variable.contains("life")){
System.out.println("TRUE");}
```

It return TRUE for both.

See solution :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\blife\\b");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("life0 is better");
        boolean b = m.find();
        System.out.println(b);

    }


}
```

Comment: **What have you tried?** Always share what you already tried.

Comment: WRT edit: **What regular expressions have you tried**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following regex: -

```
"\blife\b"
```

with [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and `Matcher` class. This will match for complete word. (`\b` denote word boundary)

You would have to use [`Matcher#find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method, to check whether a string contains this pattern.

---

**Note: -** If you want to use `String.matches`, which would be appropriate here, than going with `Pattern` and `Matcher`, you would have to add `.*` in the front and the `end`. Because, `String.matches` matches the whole string.

For e.g: -

```
String str = "asdf life asdf";
System.out.println(str.matches("\\blife\\b"));       // Prints false

System.out.println(str.matches(".*\\blife\\b.*"));  // Prints true
```

In the second Regex, `.*` matches the string before and after `life`.

Comment: Wouldn't simply using `String.matches(String pattern)` be far easier than using the `Matcher` class? --- I mean, I think you are kinda overkilling... --- I believe the `Matcher` class should only be used directly if you want to **extract** the matches. Not for simple comparisons / boolean-checks.

Comment: @TheLima.. And doesn't `String.matches` matches the complete string? `\blife\b` can be a substring. That's why I suggested using `Matcher.find`.

Comment: @TheLima.. See my updated post. You will get an idea about what I'm saying. :)

Comment: @Rohit_Jain - I know that. My point is that, for a simple yes/no check, its unreasonable to implement something like `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\blife\\b").matcher(str);   boolean check = m.find();` instead of a simple change to the pattern, `boolean check = str.matches(".*\\blife"\\b.*)`. --- In my opinion (and what I actually practice), instances of `Matcher` should only be used if you want to extract the matches (Ex: `List l = ...; /*...*/ while(m.find){l.add(m.group};}`) or in special cases such as inclusive matching things that begin/end/contain `\\b`, such as matching `"11.25%"`.

Comment: @TheLima.. Yeah actually you are right. And that's why I have updated my post to reflect that thing. Thanks for pointing. :)

Comment: @TheLima.. Also note, you need `.*?` a reluctant quantifier at the start..  `.*?\\blife\\b.*`

Comment: BTW, now that you actually included and explained the `String.matches()` solution, I think your answer is better than @Anony 's. Thus, you deserve a [+1] as well. =)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19443/discussion-between-thelima-and-rohit-jain)

Answer (score 4):

Use word boundary `\b` matches.

See the Java [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) documentation for details.

Note that you may need to write it at `\\b` to get proper escaping. The pattern needs the string `\b`, which when used in `.java` code (and not read e.g. from a file!) needs to be written in Java-escaped form as `"\\blife\\b"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `String.matches()` method and Regex `\b` to match word boundaries.

```
public class StringChecker {    
  String variable1 = "My life is better ";
  String variable2 = "My life01 is better";

  System.out.println("variable1: " + containsString(variable1));
  System.out.println("variable1: " + containsString(variable2));
  //Returns true if the string contains "life"
  public boolean containsString(String s){
    return s.matches(".*(\\blife\\b).*");
  }
}
```

Comment: still both are false. Please test it first.

Comment: @Makky - You solution, although result-wise correct, is practice-wise probably **incorrect**. [See my comment to Rohit's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343160/java-regular-expression/13343439#comment18208922_13343215). --- Not to mention that, if you want to answer your own question, you should: 1) Not do it with a question based on an issue that has already been [answered](http://tinyurl.com/d62zz5f) [many](http://tinyurl.com/bjgbcog) [times](http://tinyurl.com/cxkw5go). 2) Post your answer as an actual answer. --- PS: Nice to see Rohit 's answer to other similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.rampukar;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class DemoRegx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String email = "ram@example.com";
        String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@" + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
        Pattern pt_mail = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher mt_mail = pt_mail.matcher(email);
        if (mt_mail.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("In-Valid");
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------");

        String name = "Ram Pukar";
        Pattern pt_name = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z ]{2,}");
        Matcher mt_name = pt_name.matcher(name);
        if (mt_name.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("In-Valid");
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------");

        String user = "ram123";
        Pattern pt_user = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}");
        Matcher mt_user = pt_user.matcher(user);
        if (mt_user.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("In-Valid");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?